# How to save changed data in datagridview which is bound to a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Hi i was wondering how i would go about using an button to save changes made to order_status column in datagridview which is bound to a datatable. I've found a few things that are similar but i got confused trying to adapt the code. Please try to explain as simply as possible as i'm a complete novice, but any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
Public Class processorders
    Dim sql As New sqlcontrol
    Dim dset As New DataSet1


    Private Sub Settings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.DataTable1' table
        Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.DataTable1)
        'this line centers screen
        Me.CenterToScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgZuw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The grid id irrelevant.  If the `DataTable` contains changes then you save them by calling `Update` on the same table adapter that you called `Fill` on to retrieve the data in the first place.

Comment: Could you at least point me in the right direction so i can do the research myself?

Comment: If you seriously don't know how to call a method then you really need to stop what you're doing, find a beginners tutorial and work your way through it. I think it more likely that you do know how to call a method and you just haven't actually tried to think at all about what I said. Look at the code you have.  You can see where it's calling `Fill`.  Can you not derive any clues from that as to how you might call `Update`?

Comment: there's no need to be rude about i did say to explain as simply as possible as i'm a complete novice, as in i've been working on these for a matter of days. Here's what i tried to do when i saw that but it's not working so far: "
Me.DataTable1BindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.DataTable1TableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet1.DataTable1) "
i put that within a try/catch block and it says "system.notimplimentedexception: the method or oporation is not implimented"

Comment: Nevermind i just found out it doesn't allow me to update the database because it's a query featuring a JOIN

Comment: If you try something and it doesn't work then you need to say so because we won't know what you don't tell us.  What you did is correct but it appears that your table adapter has no `Update` method.  How exactly was that table adapter and corresponding `DataTable` generated?  Usually the wizard creates them based on a database table and adds the `Update` method automatically. If the method has not been added it's because that table adapter can't save changes, but the question is why that is the case.  Is the source perhaps a stored procedure?

Comment: OK, your comment got in just before mine. It doesn't mean that you are unable to update the database, just that the wizard can't generate the code to do it automatically.  You can still write that code for yourself.  In the DataSet designer, you can set the `UpdateCommand` property of the table adapter and write your own SQL to perform the update. That will generate an `Update` method. You won't be able to update more than one table for some database, e.g. Access, but some will let you write multiple UPDATE statements, e.g. SQL Server.

Comment: Ah that make sense. Thanks for your help, but sorry one last thing where do i go to enter this code? I can't seem to find the option from within the dataset designer

Comment: If you haven't already, double-click on the XSD in the Solution Explorer to open the DataSet designer.  You would then select your table adapter and open the Properties window.  You should see that the `UpdateCommand` property has no value.  You can create a new command from the drop-down in that property node.  You might like to look at an existing one to get an idea of SQL, parameters, etc.